# How to add multiple objects to a class in Javascript, and after see them somewhere?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that contains data. The action is to click on a button and some new data joins the object.

The problem is that when I click on the button, the last data added vanishes and the new one appears. What can I do to access both of them?

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: class Persona {
    constructor (_nombre, _seccion, _mail ){
        this.nombre=_nombre
        this.seccion=_seccion
        this.mail=_mail

Comment: window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio(){
document.getElementById("agregar").addEventListener("click", proceso);
}
function proceso (){
    aver()
}
function aver(){
    var a= document.getElementById("idNombre").value;
    var b= document.getElementById("idSeccion").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("idMail").value;
   let d= a+" - Seccion: "+b+" - "+c;

Comment: Please provide some code you already have.

Comment: @francoRoSadilla It would be better if you had edited your post with the code since it's really hard to read when the code is not formatted.

Comment: sorry, im pretty new herem idk how to even use the website

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
  let object = {
     'name' : "wassaf",
     "data" : "something"
  }

 console.log(object)
 object = {
     ...object,
     "newDataKey" : "newData"
 }
 console.log(object)
```